# Bash script. Sign in as user, run a command, sign out

Tags: bash, sudo

Hey guys I am pretty new to bash.
I am creating a simple logger all I want to achieve is to log in as super user so (sudo su) run some code (write to a file) and then log out as super user THEN execute the rest of the code

Here is my example:

```
 read -p "Are you sure you want to log this?" -n 1 -r
if [[ $REPLY =~ ^[Yy] ]]
    then
    sudo su
    if [ "$EUID" -ne 0 ]
    then
        echo $log >> ~/Logs/logs.txt            
    fi
    exit
fi
echo "DONE"
```

I am really struggling to find a solution there are examples but nothing as simple as this (what I can find that is)

Thank you if you find the time to assist.

Comment: Write a script for the code you want to run as sudo, and then put an exception in the sudoers file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will get an interactive session if you do a `sudo su` - perhaps you should just execute the command to write the log instead:

```
read -p "Are you sure you want to log this?" -n 1 -r
if [[ $REPLY =~ ^[Yy] ]]
then
 sudo bash -c "if [ \"$EUID\" -ne 0 ]; then echo $log >> ~/Logs/logs.txt; fi"
fi
echo "DONE"
```

Comment: This will still prompt for a password if they haven't updated sudoers.

Comment: It will. OP hasn't said anything about a password prompt being a problem.

Comment: What you said was 100% what I asked for @arco444